# Split two arrays into sub arrays then join sub arrays at similar indexes together

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 arrays, together equal a length of 50.

I'd like to merge both sets of data in sequence...  So for every 6 numbers, there are 4 letters.

So I'm returned something like this:

```js
const merged = [1,1,1,1,1,1,'A','A','A','A' ... * 5]
```

```js
const n = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
const a = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"
          , "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"];

const merged = [...Array(n.length + a.length).keys()].map((i) => {
  if (
    i === 6 ||
    i === 7 ||
    i === 8 ||
    i === 9 ||
    i === 16 ||
    i === 17 ||
    i === 18 ||
    i === 19 ||
    i === 26 ||
    i === 27 ||
    i === 28 ||
    i === 29 ||
    i === 36 ||
    i === 37 ||
    i === 38 ||
    i === 39 ||
    i === 46 ||
    i === 47 ||
    i === 48 ||
    i === 49
  ) {
    const item = a[0];
    a.shift();
    return item;
  }

  const item = n[0];
  n.shift();
  return item;
});

console.log( merged )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

This works fine.  It just seems overkill?

I did also try something like this - But that got pretty hectic pretty quickly too...

```js
const idx = i + 1;
  if (idx % 7 === 0 || idx % 8 === 0 || idx % 9 === 0 || idx % 10 === 0) {
```

Any thoughts would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest (most straightforward) is probably

```
const merged = [];
// assert: n.length == 30 && a.length == 20
let i=0, j=0;
while (merged.length < 50) {
    for (let k=0; k<6; k++)
        merged.push(n[i++]);
    for (let k=0; k<4; k++)
        merged.push(a[j++]);
}
```

or if you don't mind destructiveness

```
const merged = []
while (a.length || n.length) {
    merged.push(...n.splice(0, 6));
    merged.push(...a.splice(0, 4));
}
```

but sure you can also do it arithmetically:

```
const merged = Array.from({length: 50}, (_, index) => {
    const rem = index % 10;
    const round = (index-rem) / 10;
    return r < 6
        ? n[round * 6 + rem]
        : a[round * 4 + rem - 6];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const n = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
const a = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"];

const merged = n.reduce((acc, val, index) => {
  const iteration = parseInt(index / 6);
  return index % 6 === 5
    ? [...acc, val, ...a.slice(iteration * 4, iteration * 4 + 4)]
    : [...acc, val];
}, []);

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's write a function that takes an array and slices it into *n* chunks:

```js
const group =
  (n, xs, ret = []) =>
    xs.length <= n
      ? [...ret, xs]
      : group(n, xs.slice(n), [...ret, xs.slice(0, n)]);

group(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
//=> [ [1, 2]
//=> , [3, 4]
//=> , [5, 6]
//=> , [7, 8]]
```

Then let's write a function that takes two arrays of chunks and join chunks at similar index together. (Stopping as soon as one array of chunks is exhausted.)

```js
const Nil = Symbol();

const join =
  ([x = Nil, ...xs], [y = Nil, ...ys], ret = []) =>
    x === Nil || y === Nil
      ? ret
      : join(xs, ys, ret.concat(x, y));

join([[1, 2], [5, 6]], [[3, 4], [7, 8]]);
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Putting everything together:

```js
join( group(6, [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
    , group(4, ["A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"]));

//=> [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, "A", "A", "A", "A"
//=> , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, "A", "A", "A", "A"
//=> , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, "A", "A", "A", "A"
//=> , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, "A", "A", "A", "A"
//=> , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, "A", "A", "A", "A"]
```